# How can I upload files to S3 using multer without having multer store a copy of the files locally?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, file-upload, multer

I am trying to upload files to S3 using an api that accepts multipart/form-data, without using multer the body is empty but after using it all is fine.
However, multer stores a copy of every file locally and this is not something I really want.
I do not really want to use multer-s3-v3 either, since I'm trying to send back the progress of the file using socket.io, which won't work if I use it.
Any idea on how to prevent multer from saving copies? or any other method I should use?

Here's my code:
The route

```
const multer  = require('multer')
const upload = multer({ dest: 'images/' });
router.post('/image-upload', upload.single('image'), authController.imageUpload);
```

The api

```
exports.imageUpload = async (req, res) => {
  const imagePath = req.file.path;
  console.log(imagePath);
  const blob = fs.readFileSync(imagePath);
  const uploadedImage = await s3
    .upload({
      Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET,
      Key: `images/${req.file.originalname}`,
      Body: blob,
    }).on('httpUploadProgress', function(progress) {
      let progressPercentage = Math.round(progress.loaded / progress.total * 100);
      console.log(progressPercentage);
    })
    .promise();
  if (uploadedImage) {
    return res.status(200).send({
      message: "Image uploaded successfully",
      image: uploadedImage.Location.substring(36),
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you said "I do not really want to use multer-s3-v3 either, since I'm trying to send back the progress of the file using socket.io"
then use cloudinary to store files easily and its kinda free
do check this link
https://cloudinary.com/blog/node_js_file_upload_to_a_local_server_or_to_the_cloud

Comment: Unfortunately, I am required to use s3 for this project, is there any other solution?

Comment: you should then directly use express-fileupload   , you don't need to store the file first just take the file from user and apply destructuring to get the file from request.files and put it on the s3 bucket  https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload

Comment: I did not know this package existed! It solved the issue! Thanks!

Comment: cheers have a great programming journey

Comment: Please consider inserting key quotes from the linked article or summarizing its key points.